How Change value of a Flutter DropDown based on another value
Cannot figure out how to change the "initialValue" of a DropDown menu...
here and example: Once you've selected a new item in the 1st dropdown, onChange should trigger the 2nd DropDown to a new "initial value"
This is an example, I'm working on a settings page where I'm selecting from a list of "items" and based on this selection the "initial value" of the DropDownMenu changes so then he can be modified starting from the actual setting...
Thank you so much!
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: const Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: MyFirstDropDown()),
          Expanded(child: MySecondDropDown()),
        ],
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}

class MyFirstDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFirstDropDown({super.key});

  @override
  MyFirstDropDownState createState() => MyFirstDropDownState();
}

class MyFirstDropDownState extends State<MyFirstDropDown> {
  List<String> items = ["first", "second", "third", "last"];
  String dropDownValue = "";

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropDownValue = items.first;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      value: dropDownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      items: items.map((dynamic items) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
          value: items,
          child: Text(items),
        );
      }).toList(),
      // After selecting the desired option,it will
      // change button value to selected value
      onChanged:(newValue) {
        setState(() {
          ///CHANGE THE SECOND DROPDOWN,
        });
      },

    );
  }
}

class MySecondDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const MySecondDropDown({super.key});

  @override
  MySecondDropDownState createState() => MySecondDropDownState();
}

class MySecondDropDownState extends State<MySecondDropDown> {
  List<String> items = ["first", "second", "third", "last"];
  String dropDownValue = "";

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropDownValue = items.last;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String?>(
      value: dropDownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      items: items.map((dynamic items) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
          value: items,
          child: Text(items),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropDownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}


If you have mulitple widgets that need to share observable state, you need a state management solution.  I recommend Riverpod.

Ive modified the code.
Please check and make changes according to your requirements
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //added variables
  String? dropDownValue1;
  String? dropDownValue2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: MyFirstDropDown(
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  dropDownValue1 = value;
                  //your logic goes here
                  //implement the logic for changes
                  print('SetState for Dropdown 1');
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: MySecondDropDown(
              initialValue: dropDownValue1,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  dropDownValue2 = value;
                  //your logic goes here
                  //implement the logic for changes
                  print('SetState for Dropdown 2');
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyFirstDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  //added parameter for callback
  final ValueChanged onChanged;
  const MyFirstDropDown({required this.onChanged, super.key});

  @override
  MyFirstDropDownState createState() => MyFirstDropDownState();
}

class MyFirstDropDownState extends State<MyFirstDropDown> {
  List<String> items = ["first", "second", "third", "last"];
  String? dropDownValue; //made nullable

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropDownValue = items.first;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      value: dropDownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      items: items.map((dynamic items) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
          value: items,
          child: Text(items),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        //todo modify the implementation accordingly
        widget.onChanged(newValue);
        setState(() {
          dropDownValue = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}

class MySecondDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  //added parameters
  final String? initialValue;
  final ValueChanged onChanged;
  const MySecondDropDown(
      {this.initialValue, required this.onChanged, super.key,});

  @override
  MySecondDropDownState createState() => MySecondDropDownState();
}

class MySecondDropDownState extends State<MySecondDropDown> {
  List<String> items = ["first", "second", "third", "last"];
  String? dropDownValue; //made nullable

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropDownValue = widget.initialValue ?? items.last; //if there is no initial value, last item will be selected
  }
  
  //added to check for changes on build
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(val){
    super.didUpdateWidget(val);
    dropDownValue = widget.initialValue ?? dropDownValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String?>(
      value: dropDownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      items: items.map((dynamic items) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
          value: items,
          child: Text(items),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        widget.onChanged(newValue);
        setState(() {
          dropDownValue = newValue;
        });
        
      },
    );
  }
}


https://gist.github.com/AIbertRoy/a342a4244653efa601ac557011fe3943

thank you, I've tried but it look like is an issue with a package I'm using... still don't understand why see here my other post with an actual example (if you want) https://stackoverflow.com/q/78855297/13599624

@Mirakle i've verified the code i've just mentioned. Have you verified it?
The issue you are facing is basically because you are calling setState inside the child widgets . So effectively those child widgets will get rebuld. If you want the whole thing to be updated, you should manage the state inside the parent widget.
